# How to draw line between two points in raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Hy, I want to draw line between two points in raphael. How I can do this. Maybe there some examples. Thanks)

Comment: :http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/raphael/intro/

Comment: i can daw circle and other, but i want to draw line between circles...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var line = paper.path( ["M", startX, startY, "L", endX, endY ] );
```

where startX startY endX endY is your coordinates :)